# Creating sliding on/off Switch button in javaFX

Tags: javafx

Can anyone please suggest me a method to create a on/off switch button like as the image shown below, using JavaFX.

[image]

I have tried to find a method but couldn't get it.

Answer (score 13):

**Update**

ControlsFX has a [ToggleSwitch](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/ToggleSwitch.html) control.

[image: ToggleSwitch]

---

I had created a simple ToggleSwitch using JavaFX. It is a very basic model, but will help you to understand how you can go along with a more complex control of your own.

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/TheItachiUchiha/12e40a6f3af6e1eb6f75) to my code.

In case you are wondering, how it looks :

[image]

There are few other ToggleSwitches available (which I have never tried) :

1. [JFXtras](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-styles/blob/master/src/jmetro8/ToggleSwitch.java)
2. [JavaFX Metro Theme ToggleSwitch](https://pixelduke.wordpress.com/2014/07/01/toggle-switch-for-java/)

Comment: Thanks but i am actually trying to create a toggle switch  button like this 
https://proto.io/freebies/
in javaFX. Can you suggest  a method to create such a toggle switch button ??

Comment: This is just a basic example. You can use [animation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm#CIHHAACG) and css to create a similar effect for your ToggleSwitch as well.

Answer (score 11):

4 years late to the party, but maybe more people stumble upon this question.
[I modified ItachiUchiha's code snippet a little.](https://gist.github.com/meiswjn/dd64f0706085cab336e30ac7e2ef59b1) It's just another design with the circle overlapping the bar.

[image: SwitchButton]

```
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class SwitchButton extends StackPane {
    private final Rectangle back = new Rectangle(30, 10, Color.RED);
    private final Button button = new Button();
    private String buttonStyleOff = "-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 2); -fx-background-color: WHITE;";
    private String buttonStyleOn = "-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 2); -fx-background-color: #00893d;";
    private boolean state;

    private void init() {
        getChildren().addAll(back, button);
        setMinSize(30, 15);
        back.maxWidth(30);
        back.minWidth(30);
        back.maxHeight(10);
        back.minHeight(10);
        back.setArcHeight(back.getHeight());
        back.setArcWidth(back.getHeight());
        back.setFill(Color.valueOf("#ced5da"));
        Double r = 2.0;
        button.setShape(new Circle(r));
        setAlignment(button, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        button.setMaxSize(15, 15);
        button.setMinSize(15, 15);
        button.setStyle(buttonStyleOff);
    }

    public SwitchButton() {
        init();
        EventHandler<Event> click = new EventHandler<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event e) {
                if (state) {
                    button.setStyle(buttonStyleOff);
                    back.setFill(Color.valueOf("#ced5da"));
                    setAlignment(button, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                    state = false;
                } else {
                    button.setStyle(buttonStyleOn);
                    back.setFill(Color.valueOf("#80C49E"));
                    setAlignment(button, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                    state = true;
                }
            }
        };

        button.setFocusTraversable(false);
        setOnMouseClicked(click);
        button.setOnMouseClicked(click);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, but I would add a `prefSize` or `maxSize` because I put it in a `VBox` for instance, and it became too big.

Comment: Thats weird - do you use USE_COMPUTED_SIZE on the Switch? Also as the switch extends StackPane (which extends Region) you should be able to use prefHeight and prefWidth :)

Comment: No, just added the button to the `VBox` and it extended to the size of the largest component in it.

Comment: [VBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#fillWidthProperty) may fill available width. You can either set the fillWidth property of the VBox to false or add maxHeight and maxWidth to the Switch. @trilogy

Comment: Animated version in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036432/animate-custom-switch-button/73043801#73043801).

Answer (score 0):

Another Variation for those interested...

```
public class ToggleSwitch extends GridPane {

Circle knob;
Label lblDesc;

BooleanProperty isOn;

public ToggleSwitch() 
{
    // Sizing
    ColumnConstraints colThird = new ColumnConstraints();
    colThird.setPercentWidth(100d/3d);
    getColumnConstraints().addAll(colThird,colThird,colThird);
    setMaxHeight(25);
    setMaxWidth(90);
    setMinHeight(25);
    setMinWidth(90);
    
    // Property
    isOn = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    
    // Knob
    knob = new Circle(12.5);
    knob.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #ABABAB;");
    knob.setFill(Color.GRAY);
    
    // Description Label
    lblDesc = new Label("Off");
    lblDesc.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    GridPane.setHalignment(lblDesc, HPos.CENTER);
    
    // Click
    setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        isOn.set(!isOn.get());
        paintSwitch();
    });
    
    paintSwitch();
}

/**
 * Adds a listener for when the toggle changes
 * @param listener
 */
public void addListener(ChangeListener<Boolean> listener) { isOn.addListener(listener); }

/**
 * Draws the switch
 */
private void paintSwitch() 
{
    getChildren().clear();
    
    if(isOn.get()) 
    {
        add(knob, 2, 0);
        lblDesc.setText("On");
        add(lblDesc, 0, 0, 2, 1);
        GridPane.setHalignment(lblDesc, HPos.CENTER);
        setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #b0dea0; -fx-border-radius: 30;-fx-border-width:2; -fx-border-color: #ABABAB;-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 1);");
    }
    else 
    {
        add(knob, 0, 0);
        lblDesc.setText("Off");
        add(lblDesc, 1, 0);
        setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #D6D6D6; -fx-border-radius: 30;-fx-border-width:2; -fx-border-color: #ABABAB;-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 1);");
    }
}

/**
 * Sets the switch value
 * @param value
 */
 public void setValue(boolean value) { isOn.set(value); paintSwitch(); }

}
```