# One control many click listeners

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am using a custom switch button from the answer [CustomButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593193/creating-sliding-on-off-switch-button-in-javafx#answer-57290206). As you can see in the **constructor** a click listener will be set to both button and the object itself. In the **MainController** class, I created an instance of it and set a mouse click event listener in order to update the UI depending on its state of it, but that led to a weird behavior where on some clicks the button toggles and changes color sometimes the UI will be updated...

This is how I am creating and adding click listener in **MainController**:

```
filterSwitchButton = new SwitchButton();
    filterSwitchButton.setId("filterSwitchButton");
    HBox.setMargin(filterSwitchButton, new Insets(0, 20, 0, 50));
    filterSwitchButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            // update UI
        }
    });
```

How can I update the UI and change the state of the switch button when it is clicked?

Comment: It's not really clear what's going wrong. To update the UI, you should just have to call the needed methods inside the on-click handler. I will say that `setOnMouseClicked` will replace the old handler; if you want multiple on-click handlers then you should use `addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, theHandlerInstance)`. If that doesn't help, then please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer to a related earlier question:

- [Animate custom switch button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036432/animate-custom-switch-button)

exposes an `on` property modeling the switch state.

The solution is similar to the [updated answer by SephB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73043777/1155209).

If the developer wants to do something when the `on` property state changes, they can listen to the `on` property, rather than using event handlers on exposed internal nodes in the control.  As many such property change listeners as desired can be added to the property.

Similarly, the `on` property can be used to change the switch state, which will be reflected in the UI and the resultant change event will also be propagated to any defined listeners.

For example:

```
Switch lightSwitch = new Switch();
lightSwitch.onProperty().addListener((observable, wasOn, nowOn) -> {
    System.out.println(nowOn ? "on" : "off");
});

lightSwitch.setOn(true);
```

Will print "`on`".

Answer (score 5):

The button from the question you linked to may not be an appropriate starting place.

It calls `setOnMouseClicked` to add it's custom functionality, but the user of it (you in this case) would be expected to also call that to add your own functionality.

To make it work as is you could get the current reference and then call that at the start of your own handler. Like:

```
filterSwitchButton = new SwitchButton();
filterSwitchButton.setId("filterSwitchButton");
HBox.setMargin(filterSwitchButton, new Insets(0, 20, 0, 50));
EventHandler<MouseEvent> existingEvent = filterSwitchButton.getOnMouseClicked();
filterSwitchButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        existingEvent.handle(event);
        // update UI
    }
});
```

Edit:
This button should work better for you. It uses a more javafxy way of handling it and setting the mouse clicked handler should work closer to what you expect. Probably still not perfect, but it should work right away and you can learn by improving it later. It will also allow you to control the state from code as well as the handler.

```
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class SwitchButton extends StackPane {
    private final Rectangle back = new Rectangle(30, 10, Color.RED);
    private final Button button = new Button();
    private final String buttonStyleOff = "-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 2); -fx-background-color: WHITE;";
    private final String buttonStyleOn = "-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 2); -fx-background-color: #00893d;";
    private final BooleanProperty state = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    private void init() {
        getChildren().addAll(back, button);
        setMinSize(30, 15);
        back.maxWidth(30);
        back.minWidth(30);
        back.maxHeight(10);
        back.minHeight(10);
        back.setArcHeight(back.getHeight());
        back.setArcWidth(back.getHeight());
        back.setFill(Color.valueOf("#ced5da"));
        Double r = 2.0;
        button.setShape(new Circle(r));
        setAlignment(button, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        button.setMaxSize(15, 15);
        button.setMinSize(15, 15);
        button.setStyle(buttonStyleOff);
        state.addListener(observable -> {
            if (state.get()) {
                button.setStyle(buttonStyleOff);
                back.setFill(Color.valueOf("#ced5da"));
                setAlignment(button, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            } else {
                button.setStyle(buttonStyleOn);
                back.setFill(Color.valueOf("#80C49E"));
                setAlignment(button, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
            }
        });
        button.setFocusTraversable(false);
        button.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, mouseEvent ->  state.set(!state.get()));
        button.onMouseClickedProperty().bind(onMouseClickedProperty());
    }

    public boolean isState() {
        return state.get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty stateProperty() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(boolean state) {
        this.state.set(state);
    }

    public SwitchButton() {
        init();
    }
}
```

Comment: This should help, but I think the more appropriate fix is to modify `SwitchButton` to use `addEventHandler` internally, so that users of the class can call `setOnXXX` without worry of breaking the class's implementation.

Comment: @Slaw I whole heartedly agree. My answer is quick and dirty to get it working. I am working on a more complete answer.

Comment: @SephB thank you for the response, it seems the main issue was that both the button in SwitchButton class and the instance itself needed a click listener just like in the constructor, but i don't thing that that's the best way to handle it

Comment: @mOHAMEDmEHNI Check my edit for a new control.